# google maps api v3 in an asp.net 4 page

Tags: asp.net, google-maps-api-3

The following is my asp.net code for a webpage. The intellisense is NOT picking up any of the google api commands. ie, the google in new google.maps...... is squiggly lined and the map doesnt show on the page. Yes i have a width and height set. Where am I going wrong?

```
 <asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="MidPageContent" runat="server" onload="initialize">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCjtIboyk_zcd4SoE9fzNoGNzt_tIqG8jY&sensor=false">
    </script>
<script type="text/javascript">


    function initialize() {
        var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('GMap'), {
            zoom: 8,
            center: latLng,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        });
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latLng,
            title: 'Point A',
            map: map,
            draggable: true
        });
        </script>

<div id="GMap" style="width:400px; height:400px;" >
```

Comment: Im not sure why all the code on the page didn't render but here it is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry about the width, now it's another simple question, are you calling `initialize()` through `<body onload` or

`google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);`

Comment: The problem lies in the fact that everywhere in the code, the 'google" is squiggly lined in VS2010, this meaning the code isnt recognized which therefore means the maps api isnt being picked up somehow. that is the question, why? Every tutorial i have seen runs this way and a standard html page works fine in this manner. Why isnt this working inside an asp.net placeholder control